# Creating Default Thumbnail in Reactjs and Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

The article component am working on has an image but i want to replace the image with the title of the article.How can i achieve this in Reactjs and Tailwind CSS

Comment: Unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this, please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.